# Stripe.js on http:// URL

Tags: meteor, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe.js with a meteor based website. I know that when using stripe checkout or elements it has to be served on a https URL. Is this the same when just using Stripe.js? I'm setup with a test account and its working fine but not sure if it will still work on a live account.

I realize that is gives customers peace of mind to see https in the URL but is it safe to use stripe.js on a http page or is https essential for security?

Comment: No it is not safe, not for the customer, or you legally speaking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stripe.js must be loaded on a page served over HTTPS. 
If you accept card details, your page should be loaded over HTTPS for security reasons. This is one of the requirements for PCI compliance and there is no way to avoid this.